# JOIN doubles the result SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

Table 1

> Row| *click_datetime* | Date | Time | job_id | user_ip
>
> 1 | 2022-04-06 19:49:56 UTC | 2022-04-06 | 19:49:56 | 8.2246310708361155e+18 | 200.2.222.24
>
> 2 | 2022-04-06 19:47:31 UTC | 2022-04-06 | 19:47:31 | 3.0507603609338957e+18 | 200.2.222.24
>
> 3 | 2022-04-16 18:51:04 UTC | 2022-04-16 | 18:51:04 | 1.8549485175961231e+18 | 200.2.222.268
>
> 4 | 2022-04-1618:51:04 UTC | 2022-04-16 | 18:51:04 | 1.8549485175961231e+18 | 200.2.222.268

Table 2

> Row | job_id | user_ip | partner | browser
>
> 1 | 1.8549485175961231e+18 | 200.2.222.268 | 402 | Opera
>
> 2 | 1.8549485175961231e+18 | 200.2.222.268 | 402 | Opera
>
> 3 | 3.0507603609338957e+18 | 200.2.222.24 | 412 | Chrome
>
> 4 | 8.2246310708361155e+18 | 200.2.222.24 | 412 | Chrome

I need all partners from table 2 that are in table 1, but the result is doubled and duplicates come out. I have used all kinds of JOIN'S and DISTINCT. But at the output, the join doubles the result

```
SELECT t1._click_datetime_, t2.partner, t2.user_ip 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.user_ip=t2.user_ip AND t1.job_id=t2.job_id
```

the output is doubled

> Row | *click_datetime* | partner | user_ip
>
> 1 | 2022-04-06 19:49:56 UTC | 412 | 200.2.222.24
>
> 2 | 2022-04-06 19:47:31 UTC | 412 | 200.2.222.24
>
> 3 | 2022-04-16 18:51:04 UTC | 402 | 200.2.222.268
>
> 4 | 2022-04-16 18:51:04 UTC | 402 | 200.2.222.268
>
> 5 | 2022-04-16 18:51:04 UTC | 402 | 200.2.222.268
>
> 6 | 2022-04-16 18:51:04 UTC | 402 | 200.2.222.268

Comment: Those are not duplicates, they differ in `click_datetime`. In most cases like this (though you didn't explain what you are trying to do), you would want the most recent rows. There are many examples on stackoverflow and other sites on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

The join doesnt double the results, you think there are double because you dont have all the columns in the select.

In order to figure out what the issue is, Just change your SELECT clause to *:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.user_ip=t2.user_ip AND t1.job_id=t2.job_id
```

And you will see that there are no duplicates because all rows different.

If you want to keep only distinct values for the columns you selected, use DISTINCT or a GROUP BY

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1._click_datetime_, t2.partner, t2.user_ip 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.user_ip=t2.user_ip AND t1.job_id=t2.job_id
```

or

```
SELECT t1._click_datetime_, t2.partner, t2.user_ip 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.user_ip=t2.user_ip AND t1.job_id=t2.job_id
GROUP BY t1._click_datetime_, t2.partner, t2.user_ip
```